# SKNode lifetime

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

The goal I want to achieve is simple. I want certain SKNodes (or objects of a subclass) to **disappear a certain amount of time** after they were added to the scene.

This of course can be done easily by implementing a counter inside a subclass, which ticks down over time and removes the node from the scene once it reaches 0. Another idea would be to queue a *SKAction.waitForDuration:* action and one that removes the node from parent afterwards.

I hoped that there would already be something like that implemented in *SKNode*, but couldn't find anything promising.

**Am I missing something or will I have to implement that myself?**

(Note that this is more about getting to know SpriteKit and less about whether it's a hassle to implement this myself or not)

**Bonus question** if the answer to the first one is (as expected) NO:
What would be the more efficient approach, using the previously mentioned SKAction approach, or using a "lifetime" instance variable on my subclass and a method, which is called by the Scene's update: method, counting down that variable?
I might have a lot of these objects in my scene, and they might also last more than just a few seconds.

Comment: there's removeFromParent, see the skaction class reference

Comment: There's no bonus question, it's a question/answer site. Adding new questions and changing the wording of your question to make it a new question, is not the goal. You have your answer. No, `SKNode` doesn't have this capability. `SKAction` is the option provided by SpriteKit or you can use another Obj-c class or... roll your own.

Comment: My bonus answer is that you should start a new question involving the performance of SKAction vs other timer approaches. No doubt it's likely that a specific implementation of what you want is more efficient than `SKAction` which has a larger overhead due to it's larger focus. right ?

Comment: I added the bonus question long before the first one was answered, but yes, I understand that I should post it as an extra question. Should I edit it out of my initial question, or just leave it there?

Comment: The point is not when you added it, it's that you added it at all. If you are truly interested in an answer, create a new question. Keeping one question and one answer, just improves the quality of the site's content. The more questions you add to a single post, the more convoluted it becomes and therefore less efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SKNode` is not designed to handle something like timed removal.

`SKAction` was designed to handle these types of things, for example :

```
SKAction *actionWait = [SKAction waitForDuration:3];
SKAction *actionRemove = [SKAction removeFromParent];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[actionWait, actionRemove]];

[self runAction:sequence];
```

If you wanted to, you could either subclass `SKNode` and wrap that code into a method or create a category and implement that method.

Answer (score 0):

Right, no timed removal method.

A few ways to do this. Reading your question I thought about a simple method that takes a node name as a parameter, enumerates children with that name and removes them. The name would need to be unique, but could be a name given to two or more nodes to act on all of them. One approach anyway.

Something like this

```
-(void)timedNodeRemoval:(NSString *)name timer:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:name usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL stop) {
        [node removeFromParent];
        [timer invalidate];
    }];
}

// Your node creation code...


// Completion block that calls timedNodeRemoval:timer
```